# Looking for a show from the old sci fi channel that aired somewhere in mid 90s to early 2000s

Tags: story-identification, tv, alien-invasion

The one thing that stuck with me was one scene where the main character had a fight with 2 (alien maybe) goons in an alley, the goons each had a weapon called a glowfist which was a superheated glove. The gloves glowed white hot when active. It was on when it was still the "Sci Fi Channel".

The show was live action, and may have been part of a mini-series.

Comment: My impulse would be *Alien Nation*, or maybe *Dark Skies*. *War of the Worlds* would also be a decent candidate. That said, I don't remember anything with a glowing fist.

Comment: Some possibilities are *Space Rangers* and *Space Precinct*, It's been so long since I saw either that I don't remember the episodes well.

Comment: Another candidate: I vaguely remenber an episode of *Babylon 5* where a main character, possibly Sheridan, is attacked by goons in an empty corridor. I think it was a set-up to make it look like he was killed by Minbari, but my memory is vague about the details.